# Hammer JS undefined

Tags: javascript, orbit, hammer.js

I am trying to use `yepnope` with `Modernizr` and `Hammer.js` to detect and trigger touch events for a slider. This is my code. I have two errors in console and don't manage to debug. Plus I don't understand where this `<`error comes from. If I remove the following bit of code, both errors disappear.

Any clue?

```
var slider = $('#featured');

yepnope({
test: Modernizr.touch,
yep: [ "/assets/javascripts/jquery.hammer.js", "/assets/javascripts/hammer.js"],
nope: [''],
complete: function () {
        slider.hammer({drag: false}).bind("swipe", function (ev) {
        if(ev.direction === 'left'){
            slider.trigger("orbit.next");
        } else if(ev.direction === 'right'){
            slider.trigger("orbit.prev");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I have the following errors in my console.

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'slider.hammer({drag: false})')
```

Answer (score 0):

Check these two urls...
"/assets/javascripts/jquery.hammer.js", "/assets/javascripts/hammer.js"

I'm guessing that one of them is returning a html page, maybe an error page.

Also, press F12 to open up the networking tab and check that any other .js files are not loaded as html.